# How to retrieve BCC mistakenly sent to BTC Electrum wallet?

Tags: blockchain.info, electrum, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I sent my BCC from blockchain wallet to my BTC Electrum wallet and now I cannot trace them. Does not show in either of the wallets. How do i retrieve them?

Comment: Attach link to the transaction on the chain where transaction happened.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

Can you find the BCH on a block explorer website? What address are they currently in? Is it one that you control the BTC keys using electrum? If yes, then do the following:

You'll need to take the seed from your BTC Electrum wallet, and use it to generate a new BCH wallet using BCH software. Your BTC Electrum wallet will not show a BCH balance, since BCH is a different network (that uses the same addressing scheme).

It is a good idea to send ALL of the bitcoin out of your wallet, before you generate the BCH wallet using the seed. This is **important**, it ensures the keys that control your bitcoin remain safe. If the BCH software you use is malicious for some reason, it might check the BTC balance of the addresses you control, and steal the bitcoin from you.

Even if there is a small chance of this, you can be safe by just transferring all of your bitcoin out of electrum first, and then deal with the BCH.

Also, don't transfer the btc back to that wallet afterwards. You can still use electrum, you just have to make a new wallet with a seed that is different from the first one.